# Prove sequence convergence to $1$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a practice problem for a midterm in a real analysis undergrad class, but I tagged it as homework anyway.

> Let $x_0\in R$ and define $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(3-x_n)$ for $n\geq 0$. Prove that $x_n\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

To start I know that if $x_n$ is convergent then for sufficiently large $k$, $x_k$ is within the epsilon neighborhood of $x_{k+1}$. So if $x_n$ is convergent the limit is the solution to $C=\frac12(3-C)$ or $C=1$. Now if I can prove $x_n$ is convergent, it must converge to $1$, but I cannot figure out how to prove it. Any help would be great. My midterm is tomorrow unfortunately.

Comment: David, I changed your $X$’s to $x$’s to be consistent with the problem statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a simpler version of Paul’s approach. You know that you want the limit to be $1$, so look at the discrepancies $|x_n-1|$ between $x_n$ and $1$:

$$\left|\frac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_n-1}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac12(3-x_n)-1}{x_n-1}\right|=\left|\frac{1-x_n}{2(x_n-1)}\right|=\frac12\;,$$ so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-1)=0\;.$$

**Added:** By the way, the first sentence after the problem statement is true, because a convergent sequence is Cauchy, but it isn’t what you want in order to justify what follows. You want to say that if the $x_n$ converge to some $C$, then for sufficiently large $k$, $x_k$ is within epsilon of $C$ and argue from there. Alternatively, you can simply argue that if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=C\;,$$ then $$C=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12(3-x_n)=\frac32-\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\frac32-\frac{C}2$$ and continue as before.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, we have 
$$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|=\left|\frac{1}{2}(3-x_{n+1})-\frac{1}{2}(3-x_{n})\right|=\frac{1}{2}|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|.$$
From this, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence:
$$|x_{m}-x_{n}|=\left|\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}(x_{k+1}-x_{k})\right|\leq\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|=
\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}|x_{1}-x_{0}|\rightarrow 0$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
Therefore, it's convergent.

Comment: +1 for Cauchy sequence, while maybe I myself will apply  a method similar to Brian's.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $$f(x)=\frac1 2\cdot(3-x_n)$$
We can recover your sequence by setting $$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$
It can easily be seen that $|f(x)-f(y)|=\frac1 2|x-y|$, which means that it is a contraction. Therefore you know by the [Banach fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) that this function has exactly one fixed point and your sequence converges towards that fixed point. You have already calculated that this unique fixed point is $1$.

Comment: It’s fairly likely that at this point in the course David doesn’t have the Banach fixed point theorem as available as a tool. Fortunately, since he knows what the limit should be, he can still use the contractive nature of the map to get the desired result.